# Script to download ads in a page

Tags: javascript, scripting

I want to downlaod the ads present in a page. Can anyone give me some ideas how to do this.Or do you know any plugin which does this. I looked into plugins which block ads and was trying to use them to download the ads.

When I open a page in a browser i need to download all the ads which are present on that page. So I need to write a plugin or an add on to do that? I need to collect ads for one of my project.

Comment: Could you please be more clear?

Comment: Why in the world would you ever want to download ads?

Comment: What language do you know? What have you tried?

Comment: @Julian -- When I open a page I need to download the advertisements in that page.

Comment: Two questions:  1) is this for homework, 2) does it need to automatically identify which images are ads, or can the user indicate by clicking?

Comment: @ Xeon -- I know c and c++ , I donot know much of scripting . What I tried was to look at adblockers code which block ads and was trying to find the coed where they block the ads and remove the code of the ads .. but couldnt find it yet ,still digging the code of adblockerplus plugin

Comment: @chris It is not a homework . Yes it needs to identify the ads on the page by itself and download them . the user has nothing to do with this he just opens the page

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain exactly what logic you'd use to identify which images/objects are ads and which are not, but you could use the [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) Firefox add-on to script this.

In a nutshell, you'd have to loop through all suspect elements (we'll say images and objects) and check their `src` property. If an element is identified as an advertisement, pass that URL on to a webserver (could be localhost or hosted online) that will grab the file and save it.

Otherwise, I am pretty certain that the security restrictions of javascript/chrome/XUL are such that you aren't going to be able to take arbitrary content from online and write to the the local computer's hard drive silently. Imagine the security risks that would entail!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try and make some kind of browser add-on which triggers on each page load, and then use AdBlock's lists such as [this one](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt) to identify advertisements and download them. Downside is you would be making something extremely browser-dependent and you would have to parse the same kind of rules.